# How to find the rank of a matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, matrix-rank

$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
    4 & 4 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
    5 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Row-reduction is the usual way.

Comment: See [How to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, see the search/research part, and describe what you have tried, as well as what you know: it is much easier to pitch an answer at the appropriate level if you divulge that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a $4\times 4$ invertible submatrix, since its determinant is a number of the form $4k+2\neq 0$.

If you divide the third column by $2$ and perform a reduction $\!\!\pmod{2}$
you get
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
where the matrix given by the second, third, fifth, first column, namely

$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
has an odd determinant (hence it is invertible). It follows that the original matrix has rank $4$.

Comment: Columns 2 to 4 are still more obvious (+1)

Answer (score 0):

$(3, 5)$ and $(4, 2)$ are linearly independent, so it follows from inspection of the second and fourth columns that no nontrivial linear combination of rows 1 and 3 can give row 2, and (similarly) no nontrivial linear combination of rows 1, 2, and 3 can give row 4. So the matrix has full rank.

Answer (score 0):

You can operate via [Row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) or as an alternative search for the max dimension of the minor with $\det\neq0$.

Comment: @Bernard is there something wrong in my hints? Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong – maybe  a little elliptic, depending on the O.P.'s knowledge, but it's minor. In any case, it's not me who downvoted (I never downvote anyway).

Comment: @Bernard Downvotes are never a problem from my point of view when motivated from a constructive critical point of view, I was wondering in this case if something was wrong. Thank for your feedback, that's much important to me than any other up or downvoting.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation. Personally, I prefer to make observations in a comment when  needed. Then the person who posted the answer usually either deletes it if it's definitely false, or modifies it for improvement.

Comment: @Bernard You should represent the example to follow here on MSE. Thanks again!